# Android:How create ongoing notification with progress bar?

Tags: android, notifications

i am using a service in order to play background music, and i want to create an on going notification with progress bar ,on status bar, in order to user can watch the progress of current track. Can somebody help me? Thank you very much ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [custom `Notification`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView) and put something like this in your notification_layout.xml file:

```
<ProgressBar 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/notificationLoadingBar"
    android:progressDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_horizontal"
    android:indeterminate="false" 
    android:indeterminateOnly="false" />
```

Keep a reference to your `Notification` (make it global) and set the progress using [`RemoteView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html)'s API.

Sample code:

```
mNotification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.notificationLoadingBar,
    max, progress, false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works for me, now i want to create a thread in my service class in order to update my progress bar. Do you know how i can create a thread in service class.Thanks...

Comment: @Tim: Use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)